# dplyr error: object not found using rle() in mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr` to insert run lengths of column `value` into my data for each `group`.

```
tdf <- tbl_df(structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("group", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L)))
```

My data looks like this...

```
 > tdf
Source: local data frame [20 x 2]

       group value
    1      A  TRUE
    2      A  TRUE
    3      A  TRUE
    4      A  TRUE
    5      A  TRUE
    6      A  TRUE
    7      A FALSE
    8      A FALSE
    9      A  TRUE
    10     A FALSE
    11     B FALSE
    12     B FALSE
    13     B FALSE
    14     B FALSE
    15     B FALSE
    16     B  TRUE
    17     B  TRUE
    18     B FALSE
    19     B FALSE
    20     B FALSE
```

And my desired output looks like this... (notice that the run lengths restart between groups)

```
   group value run_length
1      A  TRUE          6
2      A  TRUE          6
3      A  TRUE          6
4      A  TRUE          6
5      A  TRUE          6
6      A  TRUE          6
7      A FALSE          2
8      A FALSE          2
9      A  TRUE          1
10     A FALSE          1
11     B FALSE          5
12     B FALSE          5
13     B FALSE          5
14     B FALSE          5
15     B FALSE          5
16     B  TRUE          2
17     B  TRUE          2
18     B FALSE          3
19     B FALSE          3
20     B FALSE          3
```

I figured it would just be a matter of doing this in dplyr...

```
group_by(tdf, group) %.% 
  mutate(run_len = rep(rle(value)$lengths,rle(value)$lengths))
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in rle(value) : object 'value' not found
```

I have a solution outside of dplyr using split and lapply, but would like to know how this would work in dplyr.

Comment: Your code works for me with `dplyr`. I suspect you might have `plyr` loaded as well which is messing up `mutate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution:

- `tbl_dt()` seems to be what you need.

from your `tdf` this works as expected:

```
tbl_dt(tdf) %>% 
group_by(group) %>%
mutate( run_len = rep( rle(value)$lengths,rle(value)$lengths ) )
```

#### bug?

the equivalent `tbl_df()` does not work...I do not know why...

```
tbl_df(tdf) %>% 
group_by(group) %>%
mutate( run_len = rep( rle(value)$lengths,rle(value)$lengths ) )
```

gives familiar error: `Error in rle(value) : object 'value' not found`

Comment: Good thinking to try `tbl_dt` too. I'll file a bug report on github. Thanks!